# iPhone iOS: how to detect when in roaming? (Not for jailbreaked phones)

Tags: iphone, ios, roaming

I'm coding an app with heavy network usage. I've been told to warn users for costs but only when in roaming mode. 
I know theres some way to know when the phone is roaming comparing two undocumented files on jailbreaked iphones. But I need to find out how to for non jailbreaked phones.
BTW found nothing at SCNetworkReachability api.

Ty!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any ways to detect the roaming status on iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473490/is-there-any-ways-to-detect-the-roaming-status-on-ios-6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to know if they're roaming using the API. You can find out if they're on Wifi or Cellular, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user's home network country code from CoreTelephony.
There are lists to map MNCC ( mobile network country code) to a real country code.

Next get your location, from CoreLocation, and get an address from that using geolocation.

Compare one to the other, and there you have it.

Not 100% reliable near borders, but good enough for a warning message.